# git highlighting of commit message

Tags: git, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to make git commands highlight a commit message in the terminal?

For example:

> $git stash
>
> Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 9d657ff **Sort events**
>
> HEAD is now at 9d657ff **Sort events**

Otherwise it is hard to catch them in the abundant output of git.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `--color` works for several git commands... but not for that specific one (`git stash`), and they highlight the commit hash, not the commit message.

`git stash list` is supposed to take the same options as `git log` (which includes `--color`), but I had to specify some format (e.g. `--oneline`) to get it to work:

```
git stash list --oneline --color
```

Also, git has a config option to use color in all commands by default (`color.ui`, in `git help config`)... but, like the above, it works for some commands, but not that one.

Finally, `git log` enables you to specify precisely what colors you want in the formatting, and since many commands use git log and accept options for it, you could highlight the commit message in that way, for those commands (and make aliases for them).

FWIW I agree it would be a good feature.

Comment: And how do I change colours for log? I can't find it here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Comment: @klm123: you can set `format.pretty` in the git config, but that sets only the default.  The "default default" is `git config format.pretty medium` which expands to `format:commit %H%nAuthor: %aN %aE%nDate:   %ad%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B` (I think, worked for simple test anyway).  Add `%C` directives to taste.  It would be nice to be able to define format strings and then use `--pretty=myform1`, `--pretty=myform2`, etc., but that does not seem to be an option now.

Comment: Another way is to create an alias (in `.gitconfig`), but you have to remember to use that name instead of `git log`, and it's only for that one command, so not as smooth as @torek's suggestion. e.g. I have this under `[alias]`:
`lg = "log --oneline --graph --color-words --branches  --decorate  --date=short --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %Creset%s%C(yellow)%d %Cgreen(%ar)'"` You use it as `git lg`, just like `git log`, with whatever other options, commits, paths etc you need.